# Can I (pre)view a print job from the print queue?

Tags: gnome, printing, user-interface

Inspired by Mac OSX, I wonder whether it is possible to view the *content* of a print job (e.g. the file content to be printed, not just the file name or title). Does any UI exist for that? Ideally something within gnome?

Comment: You can use the command lpq

Comment: @PraveenKumarBS thanks, but I do not see in how far this helps me to view the file content to be printed - this merely gives me the titles/file names.

Comment: Since no answers have been provided for some time, I have added feature request for gnome. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/1949 please support.